# BitmapImage.DecodePixelWidth property disappered

Tags: c#, xaml, silverlight-4.0, bitmapimage

I am completely confused. I've tried to use [DecodePixelWidth](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapimage.decodepixelwidth.aspx) property but get error: "The property 'DecodePixelWidth' was not found in type 'BitmapImage'"
Then I've tried to compile simple program with code from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.image.aspx) page:

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <Image Width="200">
        <Image.Source>
            <BitmapImage DecodePixelWidth="200"  UriSource="C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Documents\My Pictures\Sample Pictures\Water Lilies.jpg" />
        </Image.Source>
    </Image>
</Grid>
```

But this doesn't worked either. Googling gave me nothing. In C# I got same error.

Update. Using silverlight 4.0.

Comment: Silverlight, WP7 or WPF?

Comment: @EkoostikMartin SL4, updated the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `DecodePixelWidth` and `DecodePixelHeight` properties are not available for Silverlight, as you can see in the MSDN Silverlight documentation for [BitmapImage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapimage%28v=vs.95%29.aspx). `PixelWidth` and `PixelHeight` are available, but only as getter properties.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Its strange that I was able to find this property by pressing F1 on `<Image>` element while I was editing Silverlight app.